# Modify org-mode's definition of comment lines?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, comment

**Q:** how do I change `org-mode`'s definition of a commented line?

According to the manual, [`org-mode` comments](http://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-lines.html) work as follows:

> **Lines starting with zero or more whitespace characters followed by one '#' and a whitespace are treated as comments** and will never be exported. Also entire subtrees starting with the word ‘COMMENT’ will never be exported. Finally, regions surrounded by '#+BEGIN_COMMENT' ... '#+END_COMMENT' will not be exported.

I'd like to adjust the single-`#` notation to allow multiple `#`s so that Emacs will correctly fontify such lines as comments:

[image: comment lines]

I'm doing this because I have timestamp blocks at the top of the file that start with multiple comment characters:

[image: comment block]

However, I can't figure out which variables I need to adjust.  I've tried modifying `comment-start`, `comment-start-skip`, and even `comment-padding`, but with no luck (`org-comment-string` appears not to be relevant here).

So: *how can I get `org-mode` to treat lines starting with multiple `#`s as comments?*

Comment: Curious! Poking around in the source it looks like the "# " comment definition is hard-coded in a number of places, which may make it difficult to modify.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a *partial* answer that addresses the cosmetic issue (get the font-locking visuals correct), but it does not actually modify what `org-mode` considers to be a comment (e.g., for exporting purposes).

Add a font lock keyword:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(("^\\s-*#+\\s-?.*" . 'font-lock-comment-face)))
```